# javascript- pushing resultset from database to array failed

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm running a query to fetch the list of new users. Query is correct. It returns 15 users. I push the resultset into a javascript array but only the last record from the resultset is getting saved.

Here's my code:

```
var query =    `SELECT * 
                FROM users
                WHERE (status ='New')`;
var query = connection.query(query),
    response = []; // this array will contain the result of our db query
query
    .on('error', function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    })
    .on('result', function (res) {
        // it fills our array looping on each user row inside the db
        response.push(res);
        /*
        for (var key in res) {      
            if (res.hasOwnProperty(key)) response.push(res[key]);
        }
        */

    })
    .on('end', function () {
        console.log('console')
    });
```

As you can see `response.push(res);` is the line of code where I do this. Below that I have comment a few lines. I tried that option to push each row from the resultset but it ain't giving any results.

Comment: I don't think there is something wrong with the code syntax , But rather the asynchronous nature of the code , have you  tried enveloping this code inside a promise and resolving to the next then before checking the response

Comment: Not sure how to do that. This is a server I set up in nodejs (express framework) @UchihaItachi

Comment: How did you test the result? I don't see that in your code?

Answer (score 0):

try a for loop

```
for(var i in res){
    response.push(res[i]);
}
```

Comment: I tried this. When I do this or the loop I commented, it iterate a single row from the resultset and iterates each column from that particular row.  And pushes each column into a location in the response array @Amal Dev

Comment: Just check the result structure using console.dir(res);

Comment: RowDataPacket {
  id: 1700,
  status: 'New',
  u_name: null,
  u_id: null }

Comment: This is what I get when I do console.dir(res); @Amal Dev

Comment: According the data structure you are only getting a single row which is having the status as 'New' instead of 'Active' so please check your query

Comment: I ran the query in phpmyadmin. It returned 15 rows. @Amal Dev

Answer (score 0):

I maybe underestimate your test but you maybe check `result` at the wrong place.

You should do it on the `'end'` callback.

```
.on('end', function () {
    console.dir(res)
});
```